# update table column from view in another database in oracle sql developer

Tags: sql, oracle

i have 2 database in oracle.

```
DATABASE           TABLE/VIEW NAME

digidb1          CUSTOMER_REFERENCE

digidb2           CUST_REF_VIEW
```

this query will display all data in the table CUSTOMER_REFERENCE from db digidb1.

```
select * from CUSTOMER_REFERENCE

cust_id    brch_code     cust_name         description
001        001           COMPANY TEST 1    TEST COMPANY 1
002        002           COMPANY TEST 2    TEST COMPANY 2
003        003           COMPANY TEST 3    TEST COMPANY 3
```

this query will display all data in the view CUST_REF_VIEW from db digidb2.

```
select * FROM CUST_REF_VIEW

WINBBN      CUSTFULLNAME       ISINDIVIDUAL         MRGDATE
1234        COMPANY TEST 1        N                 12-03-20
4567        COMPANY TEST 4        N                 12-03-20
8901        COMPANY TEST 2        N                 11-03-20
2345        COMPANY TEST 5        Y                 10-03-20
6789        COMPANY TEST 3        N                 12-03-20
```

is it possible to update the table(CUSTOMER_REFERENCE) from database(digidb1) with this data?
i want to update cust_id column in CUSTOMER_REFERENCE from digidb1. the data will come from view CUST_REF_VIEW of digidb2.

the condition for updates are:

1. CUSTFULLNAME is equal to cust_name
2. MRGDATE is equal to system date/today (12-03-20)
3. ISINDIVIDUAL is equal to N.

my expected result is:

```
cust_id    brch_code      cust_name         description
1234       001           COMPANY TEST 1    TEST COMPANY 1
002        002           COMPANY TEST 2    TEST COMPANY 2
6789       003           COMPANY TEST 3    TEST COMPANY 3
```

Comment: In Oracle you can update only *updatable* views. More precisely, each view has updatable and non-updatable columns. You can check in the dictionary if the column you want to update is updatable or not.

Comment: sorry. i edited my post. I jumbled the results. it should be the other way.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you don't actually want to *update* anything, but *select* data from those two views by joining them, using certain conditions. If that's so, then:

```
SQL> with
  2  -- sample data
  3  customer_reference (cust_id, brch_code, cust_name, description) as
  4    (select '001', '001', 'CT1', 'TC1' from dual union all
  5     select '002', '002', 'CT2', 'TC2' from dual union all
  6     select '003', '003', 'CT3', 'TC3' from dual
  7    ),
  8  cust_ref_view (winbbn, custfullname, isindividual, mgrdate) as
  9    (select '1234', 'CT1', 'N', date '2020-03-12' from dual union all
 10     select '4567', 'CT4', 'N', date '2020-03-12' from dual union all
 11     select '8901', 'CT2', 'N', date '2020-03-11' from dual union all
 12     select '2345', 'CT5', 'Y', date '2020-03-10' from dual union all
 13     select '6789', 'CT3', 'N', date '2020-03-12' from dual
 14    )
 15  -- query you need
 16  select case when     v.mgrdate = trunc(sysdate)
 17                   and v.isindividual = 'N'
 18                   then v.winbbn
 19              else r.cust_id
 20         end cust_id,
 21         --
 22         r.brch_code, r.cust_name, r.description
 23  from customer_reference r join cust_ref_view v on v.custfullname = r.cust_name;

CUST BRC CUS DES
---- --- --- ---
1234 001 CT1 TC1
002  002 CT2 TC2
6789 003 CT3 TC3

SQL>
```

Now, depending on what you really call "database", a **database link** might to be be involved if those really are different databases, e.g.

```
from customer_reference r join cust_ref_view@db_link_digidb2 v
                                            ----------------
                                            this
```

If it is just about different users (schemas) within the same database, then you'll need to **grant** (at least) `SELECT` privilege from one user to another. It also means that you'd need to precede *remote* view name with its owner name, e.g.

```
from customer_reference r join digidb2.cust_ref_view v
                               --------
                               this
```

or - a simpler option - to create a **synonym** in one schema which will point to view in another schema. In that case, line #23 in query I posted would look exactly the same.

Comment: i really need to update the cust_id column of table CUSTOMER_REFERENCE from database digidb1.

Comment: OK; just rewrite SELECT to UPDATE.